# Composition error no idea why this happens please check it out and tell me if it was my coding or visual studio

Tags: c++, composition

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwuYZ.jpg

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Birthday' Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  12
Error   C3646   'dateofbirth': unknown override specifier   Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  16
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  16
Error   C2661   'People::People': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments  Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\main.cpp  8
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Birthday' Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  12
Error   C3646   'dateofbirth': unknown override specifier   Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  16
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\people.h  16

Comment: Code goes in the question (you can [edit] your question any time)

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page.

Comment: Add code to your question as text and use formatting options to format it. Do not attach it as screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `People.h` in `Birthday.h`, because `class Birthday` doesn't depend on `class People` at all.

What your compiler complains is that, it sees the Definition of `People` first. `People` has a member `Birthday dateofbirth`. But at this point, `class Birthday` is not defined yet.

If somehow you really need to let `Birthday` also depend on `People`, you'll create a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency), which is impossible in C++.

Comment: Thank you so much took me an hour searching for the answer really did not expect that include works that way.